# Center-align horizontal inline-block list of page numbers

Tags: css, pagination, centering, text-align

I am trying to center-align a block of page numbers at the bottom of [this page](http://patricias-needlework.com/). The HMTL and CSS looks like this:

```css
.pt-cv-pagination-wrapper {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 20px 0;
 padding: 0;
 }

.pt-cv-pagination {
 position: static;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 20px 0;
 padding: 0;
 }

li {
 position: relative;
 display: inline;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 }

.pt-cv-pagination a {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 padding: 6px 12px;
 margin: 1em;
 }
```

```html
    <div class="pt-cv-pagination-wrapper">
 <ul class="pt-cv-pagination pt-cv-ajax pagination" data-totalpages="3" data-currentpage="1" data-sid="98f4b5c3fg" data-unid="">
  <li class="cv-pageitem-prev">
   <a title="Go to previous page">‹</a>
  </li>
  <li class="cv-pageitem-number">
   <a title="Go to page 1">1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="cv-pageitem-number">
   <a title="Go to page 2">2</a>
  </li>
  <li class="cv-pageitem-number active">
   <a title="Current page is 3">3</a>
  </li>
  <li class="cv-pageitem-next active">
   <a title="Go to next page">›</a>
  </li>
 </ul>
<div class="clear pt-cv-clear-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

If you look on a narrow screen (on the live site), it will be easier to see that the page numbers are very slightly off centre. I've read several articles on here that all make sense but seem to have no further effect on my outcome. It's driving me crazy trying figure out why it's not working. Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do no post a link to an external website. Recreate the full problem in your SO snippet.

Comment: It looks center only

Comment: Looks fine in the stack snippet and on the live site; just needs the margins or font-size reducing on small mobile screens

Comment: As posted in the question it's *slightly* off-center. The '2' needs to be in the center of the gap between the elements above. This issue not alone based on mobile, it's also on desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, the art of centering elements in CSS. Good thing we have flexbox to help us all out.
This should do the trick:

```
.pt-cv-pagination-wrapper .pt-cv-pagination.pagination {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: More about flexbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox

Comment: This worked, thank you so much! It looks like I have some studying to do.

Comment: Happy studying :-) if you need any recoursing on the subject feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

The centering looks fine. If you want to have a border on the `<li>` then change the `inline` of the `li` in an `inline-block`.

```
.pt-cv-pagination li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
```

Remove the float from the `<a>` to have the block on this anchor working the correct way.

```
.pt-cv-pagination a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin: 1em;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I read the other post first and it worked immediately.